# How to run a query for year to date based on end date

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2000

I have a query that runs based on the "end date" picked.  Essentially the user picks the end date, and the query will run the report for the entire YTD based on the end date.  So for example if I select "12/3/12" it should run the report from 1/1/12 - 12/3/12.  This works if you run it ON the day... Today I tried to run it for end date "12/31/12" however I return no results because I think it's trying to get the start date based on today's date?  Below is my query:

```
SELECT        Store_Number, COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Email_Address) AS Customer_email_address, COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number) AS [Total Cars], 
                         @enddate AS End_Date, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS Start_Date
FROM            Invoice_Tb
WHERE        (Invoice_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND CONVERT(Datetime, @enddate, 102))
GROUP BY Store_Number
```

Comment: you mean you tried replacing `getdate()` with `'2012-12-03'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `GetDate()` with the `@enddate` parameter and it should work:

```
SELECT        
    Store_Number, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_Email_Address) AS Customer_email_address, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Number) AS [Total Cars], 
    @enddate AS End_Date, 
    DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @enddate), 0) AS Start_Date
FROM Invoice_Tb
WHERE (Invoice_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @enddate), 0) 
                    AND CONVERT(Datetime, @enddate, 102))
GROUP BY Store_Number
```

If you query:

```
declare @enddate datetime = '12/31/2012'

select DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @enddate), 0)
```

It will return `2012-01-01` which is what you want.